# Sending mail from express server not working on live host, in local it works fine

Tags: node.js, express, gmail, godaddy-api

Here is my express app with mail trigger:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/send_mail", cors(), async (req, res) => {
    let {text} = req.body;
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: "xxxxxxx",
            pass: "xxxxxxx"
        }
    });

    let message = {
        from: "from@email.com",
        to: "xxxxx@gmail.com",
        subject: "Enquiry from Deane Project Management",
        html: `
        <hr />
            <h1>Request for: ${text.option||"No title"}</h1>
            <span>Name: ${text.username}</span><br/>
            <span>Email: ${text.email}</span><br/>
            <span>Phone: ${text.phone||"No phone"}</span><br/>
            <span>Message:</span><br/>
            <p>${text.message||"No message"}</p>
        <hr />
        `
    }

    transporter.sendMail(message, function(err, info) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('sent',info);
        }
      });

    res.send(200);
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, () => {
    console.log("port listning on port number 4000", process.env.PORT);
})
```

all this is working fine with my `localhost:4000` but after I upload(hosted) with my godaddy account, my app works and getting success message. but did not get any mail with my box. what is the issue? any config requiem either way?

please help me.

Comment: what are the logs after you send the mail, any error or success message (your are logginf both so you should see either one)?

Comment: in client i am getting success message with code 200. but no mail received

Comment: Read second para here (https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/). make sure you have done that.

Comment: But it works fine on my localhost already. only I am not getting mails from server.

Comment: what type of server you are using or which hosting platform?

Comment: I am using godaddy server

Comment: check if port 587 is blocked on your server for outgoing traffic.

Comment: @Rajan thanks for suggestion. will check.